# Highlight text of given position inside div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, selection, highlight

I have get a position of selected word using below code:

```js
function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {

  var start = 0,
    end = 0;
  var sel, range, priorRange;
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {

    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    priorRange = range.cloneRange();

    priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
    priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
    start = priorRange.toString().length;
    end = start + range.toString().length - 1;

  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
    (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
    range = sel.createRange();
    alert(range);
    priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
    priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
    start = priorRange.text.length;
    end = start + range.text.length;

  }
  return {
    start: start,
    end: end
  }
}

function alertSelection() {
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById("myclass");
  var sel = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(mainDiv);
  alert(sel.start + ": " + sel.end);
}
```

```html
<div id="myclass" onmouseup="alertSelection()">
  <p>This is highlight text demo.</p>
</div>
```

What I want is highlight the text of that position in html text. Whatever position I give the text must be highlight in content. If user refresh the page it should not disappear.

Comment: Hi Nehal. This link surely help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991474/calculate-position-of-selected-text-javascript-jquery

Comment: This is yo want :

https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/RaOzrv

Comment: @Dilip this is not work for me. I want to highlight the word of whatever character position i will give within the range. If i give start: 1 and end : 4, "'This'" word must be highlighted.

Comment: you give those digits in textboxes ?

Comment: Try this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966821/using-jquery-to-highlight-a-character-of-a-string-on-a-webpage

Comment: Read answer of :  Rajshekar Reddy post

Comment: @Dilip but what about ending position?

Comment: wait i will make and send to you