# Highlight Searched Keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am highlighting my searched keyword - however it searches the HTML so if I have something like

```
<a href="espn.com?id=456">espn</a>
```

and search on 456 - it finds it - I don't want that.

This is what I am using

```
function highlightOnly(text) {
    $('#' + view + ' td').each(function(i, e) {
        var $e = $(e);
        $e.html($(e).html().split(text).join('<span class="matching">' + text + '</span>'));
    })
}

$('.matching').replaceWith(function() {
    return this.innerText;
});

highlightOnly($('#txtSearch').val().toUpperCase());
```

You can see original fiddle here
[Search Keyword Highlighted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56564491/search-keyword-highlighted)

Comment: you are searching for td html. You should parse the html to get just the link and highlights them

Comment: Ronald barbsan - Instead of parsing each element you can parse the text with the elements. replace below code and try.                                                                          $e.html($(e).html().text().split(text).join('<span class="matching">' + text + '</span>'));

Comment: @ganesh deshmukh - did not work